# How to add zooming/panning to image stored on Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, zooming

I would like to add zooming/panning to images that are stored on Google Storage and server them to my website. The desired effect should be similar to the one on Google Drive.
How do I attain that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for image objects in Google Cloud Storage to be zoomed, panned, edited or changed in any way. According to this documentation on [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/introduction):

> Cloud Storage is a service for storing your [*objects*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects) in Google Cloud. An object is an immutable piece of data consisting of a file of any format.

Google Cloud Storage is used to serve as an object storage for backend processing.

If you want the functionality similar to Google Drive, you may either create a function for it that you need to run on your frontend or use Google Drive as it has the necessary tools that you need.

Comment: Do you know whether Amazon or Microsoft Cloud offers panning/zooming for images?